# Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'TournamentsComponent' when ng build --prod

Tags: angular

When I run

```
ng build
```

Everything is OK, I have no warnings, no errors

But When I run

```
ng build --prod
```

I have a problem with a variable called loading:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/tournaments/tournaments-index/tournaments.component.html(1,24): : Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'TournamentsComponent'.
```

In `tournaments.component.html`, I do :

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="!loading">
```

but `loading` is not part of the component, it is part of the NavComponent that is inside all pages.

app.component.html

```
<app-nav *ngIf="auth.currentUser()"></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

nav.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  loading = false;
  avatar_src = 'assets/images/avatar/avatar.png';
  title: string;


  constructor(
    public auth: AuthenticationService,
    private nav: NavService
  ) {
  } 
  ...
```

How should I do to fix it ???

Comment: Can you show more of the HTML template, to see how the `NavComponent` is declared in it?

Comment: I added the app.component.html and nav component, so you can see how it is used. do you need anything more ?

Comment: What you added is enough. Since the `tournaments` component is loaded in a router outlet, you would have to share the `loading` property in a service. Maybe in `NavService`, or in another small `NavLoadingService`.

Comment: in NavService, I have : private loadingSource = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  loading = this.loadingSource.asObservable();

Comment: If you inject `NavService` in `TournamentsComponent`, and define a getter to access the observable: `get isNavLoading() { return this.nav.loading; }`, you should be able to use it in the HTML as `*ngIf="isNavLoading | async"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't point to variables in another component like this.(without @Input or catching Events, Subscriptions...)

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="!loading">
```

this piece of code works because **loading** is undefined and !falsy = true and also ng build does not show any error because it does not check wether if it exists or not, while ng build --prod checks it.

Your **loading** variable should be on each component and they should control wether they are ready to be shown or not

useful articles:

[AOT compiler](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

[Angular Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

> The --prod meta-flag engages the following build optimization features.
>
> Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compilation: pre-compiles Angular component templates.
>
> Production mode: deploys the production environment which enables production mode.
>
> Bundling: concatenates your many application and library files into a few bundles.
>
> Minification: removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional tokens.
>
> Uglification: rewrites code to use short, cryptic variable and function names.
>
> Dead code elimination: removes unreferenced modules and much unused code.